# Q-web...<t-if="this"> <t-call="this"> <t-else="this"> <t-call=this> but as an external container / wrapper

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

Trying to replace the header and footer on an Odoo 11 report - instead of showing our company, I wish to replace with our customers company info for unmarked delivery if a "distributor"

I have created a new Q-webs external_layout's to replace the data need to call this from shipping note

Current code states (report_delivery_document)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<t t-name="stock.report_delivery_document">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <OTHER COMMON CODE>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

I wish to change to this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<t t-name="stock.report_delivery_document">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-if="o.sale_id.partner_invoice_id.property_product_pricelist.id != 3"> <!--Identifies if not a distributor-->
            DO THIS
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            ELSE DO THIS
            <t t-call="web.DISTRIBUTOR external_layout">

                <OTHER COMMON CODE>
            </t>        
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

I know I can do this - but very poor and bulky :(

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<t t-name="stock.report_delivery_document">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-if="o.sale_id.partner_invoice_id.property_product_pricelist.id != 3"> <!--Identifies if not adistributor-->
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                 <OTHER COMMON CODE>  
            </t>                        
        </t>
        <t t-if="o.sale_id.partner_invoice_id.property_product_pricelist.id == 3"> <!--Identifies if adistributor-->
            <t t-call="web.DISTRIBUTOR external_layout">
                <REPEAT OTHER COMMON CODE>
            </t>            
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

Any direction greatly appreciated

Regards

Comment: What is the problem with your solution? What is the goal of your question?

Comment: The problem is the  <OTHER COMMON CODE>  theirs a lot of it and its just repeated twice in my solution. The goal is to create code that has a "if this do this else"  but only one  <OTHER COMMON CODE>

Answer (score 0):

You can see in odoo default the if else is use

```
<t t-if="quotation.template_id and quotation.template_id.active">
    <a t-attf-href="/quote/#{quotation.id}?#{keep_query()}"><t t-esc="quotation.name"/></a>
</t>
<t t-else="1">
    <a t-attf-href="/my/orders/#{quotation.id}?#{keep_query()}"><t t-esc="quotation.name"/></a>
</t>
```

You will try above type of code in your case it's may be helpful.

Thanks